# How to make search results not lost after refresh page on angular

Tags: angular, search

I have an application using the Angular framework. I have a search bar for the searching product name. When I type something and press enter or click, the search bar looks work well and gives me the product what I looking for. But, after I refresh the page, the product what I search before is lost. How to make it not get lost if I refresh the page?

Can someone tell me for using session storage but I don't know how to use that. I'm a newbie using angular. Thanks in advance.

My code for search function is below

```
applyFilterCustom(value){
    this.loaderService.display(true);
    this.factoryservicesService.invoke("getSearchCondition", {searchTitle: value})
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            if(data.status_code == 200){
              this.global.filterresult = data.list;
              this.global.product = data.list;
        this.global.products_condition = true;
               this.router.navigate(['products/']);
               this.loaderService.display(false);
            }
            else {
        this.loaderService.display(false);
                this.global.filterresult = [];
        this.global.products = [];
        this.global.products_condition = true;
                this.router.navigate(['products/']);
            }
        }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Angular cannot hold data once the page reloaded, you can use localstorage to store search string, after page loaded get the search string from local storage then do the same search process and show data.

Comment: We are using a service for this.

Comment: Local storage is a good way for this situation but you should be careful to clear your storage when the user is done. Also, you can create a simple and temporary JSON file to store data in it. otherwise Angular will clear variables in the relode action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage`. Try something like this:

```
var searchItem = "abc";
localStorage.setItem("searchItem", searchItem);
```

When you need to retrieve it back, do this:

```
localStorage.getItem("searchItem");
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use a **BehaviorSubject** to create an event bus service, something like this

**Service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class SearchService {

 private subject$ = new BehaviorSubject()

 newSearchEvent(product) {
    this.subject$.next(product); 
  } 

 onSearch(){
   return this.subject$;
 }
}
```

**Component:**

```
results$: Observable<Product>;

constructor(public searchservice : SearchService ) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.results$ = this.searchservice.onSearch();
}
search() {
    // get results as searchDate
    this.searchservice.newSearchEvent(searchData);
}
```